# Use xampp to allow external access from localhost. - I haven't a [# New XAMPP security concept] block

Tags: xampp

To allow external access with xampp,
I have opened httpd-xampp.conf.

By the way,

```
# new XAMPP security concept
# 
 <LocationMatch>% / (? I :(? Xampp | security | licenses | phpmyadmin |      
  webalizer | server-status | server-info) 
   ...
 </ LocationMatch>
```

I haven't a [# New XAMPP security concept] block in httpd-xampp.conf.

I am using XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2.

Where do I modify it in httpd-xampp.conf to allow external access?

Thank you

Comment: If you just need to allow external access to your xammp. Then you just need to edit the Lsten in httpd.conf file.

Comment: There is no Lsten in httpd.conf. Can I ask you what Lsten is?